# undefined reference to function error in C++

Tags: c++

I have 3 files in c++

**functions.h**

```
void handle_1(std::string line);
```

**functions.c**

```
#include "functions.h"
void handle_1(string line)
{
//do something
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    handle_1(line);
}
```

I am getting the following error-
In function `main':

```
main1.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to 'handle_1(std::string)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
g++ functions.c main.c -o main
```

Comment: functions.c does not compile. It need std::string in the parameter

Comment: then do `#include <string>` at the top.

Comment: But it will be better to rename `*.c` files to `*.cpp`, just because you want yo use C++ standard libraries